# Java equivalent to Thread.MemoryBarrier

Tags: java, c#, memory-fences

In Java, how can I explicitly trigger a full memory fence/barrier, equal to the invocation of

```
System.Threading.Thread.MemoryBarrier();
```

in C#?

I know that since Java 5 reads and writes to `volatile` variables have been causing a full memory fence, but maybe there is an (efficient) way without `volatile`.

Comment: Synchronize on the same object or read from the same volatile field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compared to `MemoryBarrier()`, Java's *happens-before* is a much sharper tool, leaving more leeway for aggressive optimization while maintaining thread safety.

A sharper tool, as you would expect, also requires more care to use properly, and that is how the semantics of `volatile` variable access could be described. You must write to a `volatile` variable on the write site and *read from the same volatile* on each reading site. By implication you can have any number of independent, localized "memory barriers", one per a `volatile` variable, and each guards only the state reachable from that variable.

The full idiom is usually referred to as "safe publication" (although this is a more general term) and implies populating an immutable object graph which will be shared between threads, then writing a reference to it to a `volatile` variable.

Comment: When using a MemoryBarrier on the writing site, possible reorderings on the reading site require in C# an invocation of MemoryBarrier also on the reading site. So an equivalent to MemoryBarrier in Java would be the following code or wouldn't it work because of optimisations? `public class Helper { private static volatile int a = 0; public static void MemoryBarrier() { int b = a; a = 0; } }`

Comment: Yes, I think that could be considered equivalent (it is not allowed to optimize away a volatile read or write); however you would be better off splitting that into a read and a write barrier. And, most importantly, you would be *much* better off writing idiomatic Java code instead of the helper class you propose.

Answer (score 2):

Java 8, via [JEP 108](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/171) added another possibility.  Access to three fences have been to the Java API, fullFence, loadFence and storeFence.

Answer (score 0):

There are no direct equivalent. Use volatile field or more high level things.

Comment: So shall I write my own helper class in Java? `public class Helper { private static volatile int a = 0; public static void MemoryBarrier() { int b = a; } }`

Comment: You can. But it is not good idea because you will work on low level. It is better to use high level things that do this work for you. I try to explain on example. You use memory barrier to guarantee visibility between write and read of variable (or several). But it is better show you intentions directly by manually puting volatile on variable declaration and let Java do it for you which remove boilerplate code and also it help you not to forget put barrier when you add new access to variable to you code.

Comment: What is wrong? See [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553233#comment39902376_25553490).

Comment: @ominug other one is ok. Yok can simplify it to `a=a;`